# XPath get text between different tags on the same level

Tags: r, xpath

I have html with the next structure (see below) and need to get all texts between <*p*><*/p*> and <*h3*><*/h3*> or <*h2*><*/h2*> which are on the same level in html structure.

Here is an example:

```
<p>..</p>
<p>..</p>
..
<p>"<em>Ce que nous voulons souligner, c'est que la Tunisie est sur la bonne voie</em>", a déclaré Mona Richmaoui, membre de la mission.&nbsp;</p>

<h3 class="intertitre title_delta">SANCTIONNER LES VIOLATIONS DES DROITS DE L'HOMME</h3>

<p>Le ministère tunisien de l'Intérieur a engagé lundi une procédure visant à la dissolution...&nbsp;</p>
..
<p>..</p>
<div>...some text over there ....</div>
..
<h2>some text</h2>
..
<p>..</p>
```

The output should be:

```
"Ce que nous voulons souligner, c'est que la Tunisie est sur la bonne voie", a déclaré Mona Richmaoui, membre de la mission. 
SANCTIONNER LES VIOLATIONS DES DROITS DE L'HOMME
Le ministère tunisien de l'Intérieur a engagé lundi une procédure visant à la dissolution...
..
some text
```

I m using the next XPath but it ignores text between <*h3*><*/h3*> tags:

```
//p//text()[normalize-space()]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are trying to get the text of *all* the elements:

`//*//text()`

If you want to specify elements:

`//p//text()|//h3//text()|div//text()`